# Как записать данные в xml файл c dataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, datagridview

В dataGridView вводятся данные с клавиатуры.
Как записать (сериализовать) данные в xml файл? И как загрузить (десериализовать) данные из xml файла, при следующем запуске программы?

Answer (score 2):

Для начала [DataTable.WriteXml Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx)

Пример:

```
   // считать с файла
    string fileName = @"C:\users\admin\desktop\data.xml";
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(fileName);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "row";
    }

     // записать в файл     
     string fileName = @"C:\users\admin\desktop\data.xml";
     dataSet = (DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource;
     dataSet.WriteXml(fileName);
```

Comment: Вылазит исключения Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataSet'. на строчке dataSet = (DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource;

Comment: @FORTRAN - это значит, что данные у вас привязаны к DataGridView через BingindSource. Соответственно, сериализовать нужно источник данных, а после десериализации по-новому привязывать его.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ds = new DataSet();
var path = @"c:\temp\gridtest.xml";
// загрузить xml из файла (если он есть) или создать новый xml.
if (File.Exists(path)) ds.ReadXml(path);
else ds.ReadXml(new StringReader("<data><row i='1'/><row i='2'/></data>"));
// вывести xml в грид.
var f = new Form();
var dg = new DataGridView() { Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
dg.DataSource = ds;
dg.DataMember = "row";
f.ShowDialog();
// сохранить xml в файле
ds.WriteXml(path);
```